# Sobolev Embeddings (reference request)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, book-recommendation

The following two results are often used in research papers:

> $$W^{2,1}_p(J\times \Omega)\hookrightarrow L^\infty(J\times\Omega)\qquad\text{and}\qquad \|u^2\|_{L^p(J\times\Omega)}\le \|u\|^2_{W^{2,1}_p(J\times \Omega)},$$
>   where $$W^{2,1}_p(J\times \Omega):=L^p(J,W^2_p(\Omega))\cap W^1_p(J,L^p(\Omega)),\qquad J\subset\mathbb{R},\quad \Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n\quad\text{bounded, smooth}$$

However, I could not find a book/article/proof I could use as a reference for these embeddings. It is not clear to me why these results hold and for which $p$ it holds. I suppose that there is a lower bound for $p$?

Comment: It looks similar to [Aubin-Lions lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubin%E2%80%93Lions_lemma), although not identical with the statement given in Wikipedia. And I would suspect there needs to be some assumption on $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adams and Fournier does not cover Sobolev spaces with values in a Banach spaces. For those your best bet is some book on evolution equations, for example Franck Boyer • Pierre Fabrie Mathematical Tools for the Study of the Incompressible Navier-Stokes Equations and Related Models  [Boyer-Fabrie](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789028602052**)
or some book on semigroups, for example Barbu, Viorel, Nonlinear semigroups and differential equations in Banach spaces
[Barbou](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789028602052**).

**Update** To get the results you need you can use the theory of anisotropic Sobolev spaces. The book you want is [Besov](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047026540X). Unfortunately, it is not easy to read. 
Consider the anisotropic Sobolev space $W_{p}^{\overrightarrow{m}}%
(J\times\Omega)$, where $\overrightarrow{m}=(m_{1},m_{2},\ldots,m_{n+1})$ is a
vector of positive integers (so you are taking $m_{1}$ derivatives with
respect to $t$, $m_{2}$ with respect to $x_{1}, \ldots, m_{n+1}$ derivatives
with respect to $x_{n}$. If $p<q\leq\infty$ and
$$
\left(  \frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}\right)  \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{m_{k}}<1
$$
then
$$
\Vert u\Vert_{L^{q}(J\times\Omega)}\leq c\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\Vert\partial^{m_{k}%
}u\Vert_{L^{p}(J\times\Omega)}+c\Vert u\Vert_{L^{p}(J\times\Omega)}.
$$

In your case $\overrightarrow{m}=(1,2,\ldots,2)$ (so you have the time
derivative of order one in $L^{p}$ and space derivatives of order two in
$L^{p}$). If you take $q=\infty$ you get
$$
\frac{1}{p}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{m_{k}}=\frac{1}{p}\left(  1+\frac{n}
{2}\right)  <1
$$
that is $p>1+\frac{n}{2}$.

On the other hand, if you take $q=2p$ you need
$$
\left(  \frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{2p}\right)  \left(  1+\frac{n}{2}\right)  <1,
$$
that is, $p>\frac{1}{2}+\frac{n}{4}$.

**[1](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789028602052**): https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-5975-0

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, see edit.

Comment: I updated my post. Hope it answers your question. Wished I had a simpler reference for you but I could not find anything better.